# Método obsoleto en la libreria commons io

Tags: java

estoy utilizando la libreria **commons.io de apache**, en concreto las clases
**FileUtils** y **IOUtils** y quería cerrar un InputStream con el método

```
IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputstream);
```

pero eclipse lo marca como obsololeto. Lo confirmé en la API y efectivamente está Deprecated a partir de la versión 2.6 sin reemplazo. 
Lo solucioné cerrando el inputstream con el método **close()**, pero me queda la duda de si no lo han reemplazado por que no es necesario al haber ya un método que lo hace o hay alguna otra razón que desconozco.

En la versión 2.5 de la API el método no estaba Deprecated y se podía utilizar.
Saludos!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No está disponible para usarse en vez de `close()`. El JavaDoc parece sugerir que sólo se use en un finally para asegurar el cierre de los recursos, pero la idea general es usar `close()` y manejar las excepciones que pueda lanzar esa operación.

```
BufferedWriter bw = null;

try {
    bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.txt"));
    bw.write("test");
    bw.flush(); // you can omit this if you don't care about errors while flushing
    bw.close(); // you can omit this if you don't care about errors while closing
} catch (IOException e) {
    // error handling (e.g. on flushing)
} finally {
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(bw);
}
```

Actualmente para Java8 es razonablemente mejor pensar en usar un try-with-resources.

Ej:

```
 try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.txt"))) {
     bw.write("test");
 }
```

Fuente: [SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14437114/236345)

Comment: ok, muchas gracias!!